# Multiple queries with results needed from each

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

Let's say i have two dbs with a structure like follows:

```
ID            CLASS          STUDENT_COUNT
1             Math              0
2             Biology           2
3             Algebra           1
4             Literature        5

ID            CLASS_ID          NAME
1             1                 Ted
2             1                 Mark
3             3                 Sally
4             4                 Sam
```

I am trying to write a query for getClassById(int id) which would return an object with a Class variable and a List variable. So far, the only way I can think to do this would be to use 2 queries. The first would query like so:

```
select id, class, student_count from t_classes where id = an_id;
```

this would return me enough info to populate the Class variable. I would then need a second query on the students table to be able to populate the List:

```
select id, name from t_students where class_id = an_id
```

Excuse my extreme SQL newbiness but is there another way to do this?

Comment: Use an inner join to relate the 2 tables in a single statement.  It's basics of SQL, you'll want to learn this one and not just take an answer.   select fields from table1 inner join table2 on table1.key = tables2.key  where id = an_id.      id and class_id are your keys here.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you one row per student:

```
select c.id, c.class, c.student_count, s.id, s.name 
  from t_classes c
  join t_students s on s.class_id = c.id
 where c.id = an_id;
```

Let us now if you want the result set in other way than that.

Comment: So, when I am parsing the result set into a Class POJO, I would just look at  the c.id and c.class for the first row and ignore the rest because they will all be the same? I would then iterate over all the fields and build my List<Student>? Is this more efficient than the 2 queries I would run above?

Comment: In that case it's better to use 2 queries, because you need to populate a second list (students).